# How to deduct 300 days from 40 years with PHP?

Tags: php, date, intervals, datediff

I would like to deduct 300 days from 40 years (14609 days) and I would like to get the results like;

xx YEARS
XX MONTHS
XX DAYS

I know I have to write my code here but the problem is, I don't know how to write the code.

Thank you.

Comment: 365*40=14600, subtract 300 = 14300 days. Where is `14609688` from?

Comment: At best, your answer will be an approximation, since the number of days in each month varies.  Also, there are only 14600 days in 40 years.

Comment: According to Google, it shows 14609.688 . I don't know why I wrote like that. Thank you for correcting me :)

Comment: So the question here really is only how to format the date when printing it, right?

Comment: Hi, my question is how to write the code to get the results like;  xx years, xx months, xx days.

Comment: @aaronxxx I need the absolute result.

Comment: is this for any 40 year span (which isn't really possible to figure out the leap years for) or is it 40 years from today, minus 300 days?

Comment: @ChrisTrudeau for example; 14610 days in 40 years (leap years included), I would like to deduct 300 days from 14610 days and I would like to get the result in xx years, xx months and xx days.. I will not deduct days from any years (like 1985), i just want to deduct the days from 14610 days..

Comment: @ivocan..The problem there..You can't never get an "truely" absolute result..all aproaches give you an approximate value..

Comment: If there is clue about 40 years..Example:Between 01-02-1976 and 04-07-2016.You can get an absolute result..

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because I don't think it is useful for other users.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Well, as NateB said, the best you can get is a close approximation. Every  year has on average 365.25 days spread across 12 months. The average month will have `(365.25/12)`, or 30.4375 days. Which gets us to the following code:

```
$total_days = 14610-300;

$total_months = $total_days/30.4375;
$days_left = fmod($total_days, 30.4375);

$total_years = $total_months/12;
$months_left = fmod($total_months, 12);

echo floor($total_years)." years, ".floor($months_left)." months, ".round($days_left)." days";
```

This returns:

> 39 years, 2 months, 4 days

Note that instead of rounding days you could do a decimal or even figure out how many hours:

```
echo floor($total_years)." years, ".floor($months_left)." months, ".number_format($days_left, 1)." days";
```

This returns:

> 39 years, 2 months, 4.4 days

I don't think you can do any better than this for what you require.

Comment: Thank you @Chris Trudeau , it works perfect!